# Comparing 2 tables and displaying rows in one table not found in the other

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I want to fin the values of [stac].[Key] + SUM([stac].[Gross Sls Qty] that are not found in table n4ac. This is what I have:

```
SELECT [stac].[Key] + SUM([stac].[Gross Sls Qty]) 
FROM @SoldToActuals stac
     LEFT JOIN @Node4Actuals n4ac 
          ON (([stac].[Key] + SUM([stac].[Gross Sls Qty])) = ([n4ac].[Key] + SUM([n4ac].[Gross Sls Qty])))
WHERE [stac].[Key] + SUM([stac].[Gross Sls Qty]) IS NULL
```

Im getting this error:

> An aggregate cannot appear in an ON clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Read up on EXCEPT statement - it might make it easier on you than trying to LEFT JOIN your way through it.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to look up WHERE NOT IN on MSDN for TSQL, this can then be reversed using the NOT Operator

Here is a link: [IN Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx)
Here is another link: [NOT Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189455.aspx)

Lastly a quick generic example:

```
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName, e.JobTitle
FROM Person.Person AS p
JOIN HumanResources.Employee AS e
    ON p.BusinessEntityID = e.BusinessEntityID
WHERE e.JobTitle IN ('Design Engineer', 'Tool Designer', 'Marketing Assistant');
```

This will select everyone who is 'Design Engineer', 'Tool Designer', or 'Marketing Assistant' and just add WHERE e.JobTitle NOT IN to get everyone who doesn't have one of those job titles

EDIT:

Here is my attempt at understanding your table structure and trying to write a relevant example from the code you posted:

```
SELECT [stac].[Key] + SUM([stac].[Gross Sls Qty]) 
FROM @SoldToActuals stac
WHERE ([stac].[Key] + SUM([stac].[Gross Sls Qty]))
NOT IN
(SELECT ([n4ac].[Key] + SUM([n4ac].[Gross Sls Qty]) FROM n4ac)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably try modifying your query a bit like

```
SELECT [stac].[Key] + SUM([stac].[Gross Sls Qty]) as some_col
FROM @SoldToActuals stac
     LEFT JOIN @Node4Actuals n4ac 
          ON [stac].[Key]  = [n4ac].[Key]
WHERE [n4ac].[Key] IS NULL
OR SUM([stac].[Gross Sls Qty]) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you could use the EXCEPT operator to do what you want?
(Example from AdventureWorks)

```
-- Create Some Sample Data -- 

select top 150
    SalesOrderID
   ,LineTotal
into #BigList 
from
    Sales.SalesOrderDetail
order by
    SalesOrderID

select top 15
    SalesOrderID
   ,LineTotal
into #SmallList 
from
    Sales.SalesOrderDetail
order by
    SalesOrderID

-- use except set math operater to find differences -- 

select 
    SalesOrderID
   ,sum(LineTotal) as SumTotal
from
    #BigList 
group by
    SalesOrderID

except 

select 
    SalesOrderID
   ,sum(LineTotal) as SumTotal
from
    #SmallList 
group by
    SalesOrderID
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is an attempt to rewrite your query, which may allow you to see (a little easier) how to get your answer.

```
SELECT  [stac].*
   FROM    ( SELECT    [Key] + SUM([Gross Sls Qty]) AS X
      FROM      @SoldToActuals
    ) AS stac
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT    [Key] + SUM([Gross Sls Qty]) AS X
                      FROM      @Node4Actuals
                    ) AS [n4ac] ON n4ac.X = stac.X
   WHERE   [stac].[Key] + SUM([stac].[Gross Sls Qty]) IS NULL
```

Here is the prefered way to write it using the "EXCEPT" operator, it is the like "UNION MINUS"

```
SELECT    [Key] + SUM([Gross Sls Qty])
      FROM      @SoldToActuals
EXCEPT 
SELECT    [Key] + SUM([Gross Sls Qty])
      FROM      @Node4Actuals
```

Here is a link to the [EXCEPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)